# Why virtual constructor not possible in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Why virtual constructor is not possible in c#. What is the difficulties, it will face, if write code like below.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual BaseClass()
    {
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass() : base()
    {
    }

    public override BaseClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited, so can't be overridden, so it makes no sense for them to be virtual. What are you actually trying to *achieve*?

Comment: @JonSkeet, all respect to you _/\\_, I can find you everywhere on stackoverflow you are a robot or human :) :p

Comment: @JonSkeet, Please excuse me if i ask anything not sensible. i expected the reason. for example, multiple inheritance is not supported because of diamond problem, likewise what is the reason behind that virtual constructor?

Comment: @RamNivas: Something only makes sense to be virtual or overridable if it's inherited. Constructors aren't inherited. If you want to ask why constructors aren't inherited, that's a different question - which has been asked already. (A search should find it for you...)